# Problems showing a ProgressDialog from a onClick method

Tags: android, progressdialog

i am trying to make a progressdialog inside a onclick, and it doesn't shows nothing

this is my code:

```
enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(GPSLoc.this, GPSLoc.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), 
                                    GPSLoc.this.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);  
}}
```

why it doesn't shows nothing? i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that your onClick listener is in fact getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i did it implementing that with an AsyncTask. Because AsyncTask manages the UIThread and a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that your are just creating the Progressdialog not actually showing it. Try adding `pd.show();` to the the onclick method after you initialize the ProgressDialog.

Comment: I'm by no means saying your wrong, but what makes it not the problem... for my benefit?